# Spring Boot Actuator: How to add metadata to metrics exported to a message channel?

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using the [message channel integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-message-channel-integration) to export Spring Boot Actuator metrics to Kafka. It works quite well but I'm wondering if it is possible to add some metadata to the message. I would like to know at least the hostname as well as the name of the service that has produced the metric.

Thanks in advance!